# jump to code from diff mode (Intellij Idea)

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, rubymine

While in diff mode (`Show Diff`) how can I go back immediately to the editor and open the file I just reviewed? What is the key shortcut for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: this feature is available since IDEA 13.1.

<s>Not possible right now, please [vote for the open issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-77540)</s>.

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-77540 It is resolved. Latest EAP for 13.1 has this feature.